# Tossing an uneven coin

Tags: probability, statistics

Two players have one uneven
coin, the probability of getting a head  is 2/3. The first person(A) throws
three times. The second(B) tosses the coin until he gets tails.
a) What is the probability that the former will throw more heads;
 from the second?
b) What is the average number of heads thrown by the two
together?

Can you help me understand how am i supposed to compare 2 probabilities and how do i calculate the average number of heads thrown by the two?Do i have to calculate the average numbers of heads for every assumption?

Comment: Are you very new to probability, or do you know for example about random variables and expectation?

Comment: Hint: The number of heads follows the Binomial distribution.

Comment: I understand what are random variables and expectations.Thanks also for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to this is by defining appropriate random variables:

$Y_1$ being the number of heads the first person has throw, and $Y_2$ being the number of heads the second person has thrown. Then by the information:

$Y_1\sim Bin(3,\frac{2}{3})$ and $Y_2\sim \text{Geom}(\frac{1}{3})$

I think there is an implicit assumption that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent. Then the desired probability is:

$$ \mathbb{P}(Y_1\geq Y_2)= \mathbb{P}(Y_1=1,Y_2=0)+ \mathbb{P}(Y_1=2,Y_2=0)+ \mathbb{P}(Y_1=2,Y_2=1) + \mathbb{P}(Y_1=3,Y_2=0) +\mathbb{P}(Y_1=3,Y_2=1)+ \mathbb{P}(Y_1=3,Y_2=2)$$

Also when dealing with probability the average number is usually the expectation, and they are probably referring to the expectation:

$$ \mathbb{E}[Y_1+Y_2] $$

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: I don’t know what you think $\text{Geom}(\frac23)$ is, but I read it as a distribution such that the probability of the outcome $n$ is $\frac23(\frac13)^n.$ That does not match the probabilities for person B. And saying $Y_2-1$ is geometric implies $Y_2\geq1,$ which is also wrong. But I think the general idea of using a geometric distribution and adding the probabilities as shown is correct.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for the correction. I was confused, and hopefully have revised it correctly.

Comment: It looks correct to me now. It _is_ geometric, and there is exactly a $\frac13$ chance the first toss is tails, leading to zero heads.

Answer (score 1):

Player A has Binomial Distribution:

P(A) distribution = $({1\over3}+{2\over3})^3 = {1\over27} + {2\over9} + {4\over9} + {8\over27} = 1$

Player B has Geometric Distribution:

P(B) distribution = ${1/3 \over 1-2/3} = {1\over3} + {2\over9} + {4\over27} + {8\over81} + \cdots = 1$

P(B<1) = ${1\over3}$
P(B<2) = ${1\over3} + {2\over9} = {5\over9}$
P(B<3) = ${5\over9} + {4\over27} = {19\over27}$

$\begin{align}
\text{P(A > B)} &= \text{P(A=1, B<1) + P(A=2, B<2) + P(A=3, B<3)} \cr
&= {2\over9}({1\over3}) + {4\over9}({5\over9}) + {8\over27}({19\over27}) \cr
&= {2\over27} + {20\over81} + {152\over729} \cr
&= {386\over729}
\end{align}$

Thus, P(A has more heads than B) = ${386\over729} ≈ 53\%$

Comment: What symmetry do i have?

Comment: Player A and B basically played the same 3-toss dice game.  You do not get any advantage using schemes.  Only the dice matters. Casino know this ...

Comment: Player B can end with 1 tail and **no** heads. Player A cannot. But player B can end with 1 tail and 4 heads, beating anything player A can do. So the symmetry argument is not obviously valid. We are not interested in whether there is a “scheme” to beat a casino; we’re just given rules for how many flips each player makes.

Comment: Thanks David K.  I think it is fixed now